# Let p be an integer other than 0, $\pm$1. Prove that p is prime if whenever r and s are integers such that p=rs, then r=$\pm$1 or s=$\pm$1

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $p$ be an integer other than $0, \pm 1$. Prove that $p$ is a prime if whenever $r$ and $s$ are integers such that $p=rs$, then $r=\pm1$ or $s=\pm1$

Since this is an if and only if proof, I started off trying to prove this statement "forward" and then "backwards". However I am not sure of my work is correct thus far.

This is what I have:

### Proof:

### (Forward)

Let $p$ be an integer and not equal to $0, \pm 1$ and $p$ is prime.
Suppose $r,s$ are integers such that $p=rs$

(NTS: $r= \pm 1$ or $s=\pm 1$)

Case $1$:

$$r \neq \pm1$$

$$p=rs $$

$p$ is prime and therefore only divisible by $\pm 1$ or $\pm p$

In this case $r$ divides $p$, but $r$ cannot equal $\pm1$.

This forces $r=\pm p$

Plugging this back into the equation: $p=\pm s$ then $s=\pm 1$

Case $2$:

$$s\neq \pm 1$$

$$p=rs$$

$p$ is prime and therefore only divisible by $\pm 1$ or $\pm p$

In this case $s$ divides $p$, but $s$ cannot equal $\pm 1$.

This forces $s=\pm p$

Plugging this back into the equation: $p=(\pm p)r$ then $r=\pm 1$

### (Backward)

Let $r,s$ be integers such that $p=rs$, $r=\pm 1$ or $s=\pm 1$

(NTS: $p$ is prime)

$$p=rs$$

Therefore $r$ divides $p$. We also know that every divisor ($r$) of a non zero integer ($p$) must be less than or equal to $|p|$, however since $r$ is an integer, $r$ must equal $1$ or $p$.

In the case that $r=1$

$$p=(1)s$$

$$s=p$$

In the case that $r=p$

$$p=(p)s$$

$$s=1$$

This is where I get really stuck because although I showed that $r$ and $s$ are essentially $1$ or $p$, I don't necessarily prove that p is prime because of the condition that that there could be more divisors than just $1$ and $p$ with what I have shown a number like $p=4$ would still work, but $4$ is not prime. What am I missing? Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your math text. This link may be useful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The first half can be done more briefly as follows:  Let p be prime and p=rs. Then p=|p|=|r|\cdot |s|, and since p is prime we must have (|r|,|s|)=(1,p) or (|r|,|s|)=(p,1), so |r|=1 or |s|=1...... For formatting, go to Help, choose the Help Center, and under "Our Model" choose "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?, read it, and go to its "Quick Tutorial".

Comment: What is your definition of a "prime integer"?  (in abstract algebra there are several possibilities).

Comment: My definition of a prime integer is an integer not equal to 0 or $\pm$ 1 and   its only divisors were 1 or itself.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong statement:

- We also know that every divisor $t$ of a non zero interger $p$ must be less than or equal to |p|, however since $r$ is an integer, $r$ must be equal to $1$ or $p$.

This is not true as we have not shown that $p$ is a prime.

Another wrong statement is the statement that you are trying to prove, the statement is true for negative of prime numbers as well.

Let any factorization of $|p|$ be $|p|=|r||s|$. Using the property that is stated, if $|r|=1$ then $|s|=|p|$. If $|s|=1$, then $|r|=|p|$. Hence $|p|$ must be a prime number.

Comment: I see where my thought process when wrong thank you!. But another question I have is how can we conclude that  |p| is a prime, wouldn't we have to prove that these are the only divisors? Say p=10 wouldn't we be able to say that this same condition also holds true?

Comment: The properties that you are using is $\forall r, s, |p|=rs$ then $|r|=1$ or $|s|=1$. The keyword is "for all" factorization. $10= 5 \times 2$, hence it doesn't satisfy the property and we can't conclude that it is a prime.

Answer (score 1):

The second implication  is a false result. If it were true we would conclude that $1$ and $-2$ are prime.  What is true is that if $p>1$, and if $|r|=1$ or $|s|=1$ whenever $rs=p,$ then $p$ is prime. Your attempt suffers from too much abbreviation.

State the initial assumptions: Let $p>1$ have the property that $|r|=1$ or $|s|=1$ whenever $rs=p.$

State the conclusion to be proved: Then $p$ is prime.

Then give the proof of the conclusion: Proof:

(I). If $r>1$ and $s>1$ then $rs\ne p,$ because otherwise $rs=|r|\cdot |s|=p$ with $|r|\ne 1\ne |s|.$ And also $p>1.$

(II). The definition of "$p$ is prime" is that $p>1$ and $p\ne rs$  whenever $r>1$ and $s>1.$ So by (I),  $p$ is prime.

Comment: I gave your Q a + vote. I dk why someone gave you a minus.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was only focused on one definition of prime and was trying to fit that mold. I do need to clean up my proof and just stick to the things I know and need to know.

Comment: My pleasure...............